# How to open semantic-ui-react modal in a different route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, semantic-ui-react

I am using Semantic UI React and React Router. What I want to achieve is that when the user opens a modal, the address should show the route that corresponds to the modal, for example when the user opens the article modal, the route should be www.example.com/article.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modal inside semantic-ui-react has a boolean `open` prop. Once you define that prop you are overriding the internal state that is controlled on the `Modal` component out of the box.

You'll need to control the open state of the component yourself to achieve this. You will need to get a parameter from your route that specifies whether the modal is open. If that parameter is present you can set the modal as open. If it is not present, you can set it as closed.

You will also need to handle the closing of the modal since it is not internal to the Modal component anymore. Probably the easiest way would be to set an onClick event on the close button that will push the router history to the previous step. Or you can push to somewhere else if you prefer to go elsewhere.

You can pass in a node (not just a string) on the `closeIcon` prop where you could actually define your own button and the click event that does the router push.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that worked for you. Please consider marking this answer as correct if it was helpful to you.